# String manipulation in Swift

Tags: swift

I'm pretty new in Swift and I was wondering what is the difference between this (that compiles successfully, and returns "A"):

```
var label = "Apoel"
label[label.startIndex]
```

and the following, for which the compiler is complaining:

```
label[0]
```

I know that label is not an array of chars like C but using the first approach, means that the string manipulation in Swift is similar to that of C.

Also, I understand that the word finishes with something like C's "\0" because

```
label[label.endIndex]
```

gives an empty character while

```
label[label.endIndex.predecessor()
```

returns "l" which is the last letter of the String.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`startIndex` is of [type `Index` which is a struct](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_CharacterView-Index_Structure/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/struct/s:VVSS13CharacterView5Index) and not a simple Integer.